# How to find what link we have clicked?

Tags: javascript, html

I my application i am having three links, on clicking the link i need to find which link has been clicked and need to pass some unique information to the next page.

Kindly help

Comment: can you tell us what is the current code of your links?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be good if you could clarify this a bit. Because there are many ways if solving this without Javascript...

You can either add a paramater to the URL link that is clicked. For instance instead of:

```
<a href="about.php">About</a>
```

Use:

```
<a href="about.php?clicked=about">About</a>
```

Then simply use that value in using Javascript on the following page by using for instance this script: http://snipplr.com/view/799/get-url-variables/

If you are using a server-side scripting language like PHP you can pick up on what page *refered* to the page your on.

```
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']
```

There are more examples, just comment on this if you want me to give you more.

Comment: on the click i want to go to a servlet and in the servlet i want to get that information.

Comment: You can try to use `request.getHeader("Referer");` More info in link: http://bit.ly/c4Y2Pb

Answer (score 3):

Like this `<a href="/newpage?some_key=somevalue">link</a>`

You'll need to query the parameters on the receiving page, though you could also use a target '#data' and query that.

[This site](http://www.netlobo.com/url_query_string_javascript.html) has an example implementation of reading URL parameters